# Linux SSH from C

Tags: c, linux

i'm using SSH to connect to other computer by using C file. In terminal I use this code

```
ssh sakurachan@192.168.61.10
```

How can I do this in C? I need the user to type the IP and the computer. Currently I have this code:

```
char name[100];
char ip[100];
printf("Enter the computer name to connect: ");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("Enter the ip to connect: ");
scanf("%s", ip);
char command[150];
strcpy(command, "ssh ");
strcat(command, name);
system(command);
```

the code can't be run. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So what happens ? And shouldn't you concatenate an "@" and the `ip` too ? If you print out your `command`, you will see which command you're trying to run, which should be helpful to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [libssh](http://libssh.org/) if you are programming in C and use proper C functions to do that. Bash-ing in C is pretty ugly (imho).

`libssh` has pretty good documentation and nice [tutorials](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html). Try this.

Comment: The chances that `system()` is the correct, let alone *best*, solution for *anything* are quite slim. Hence, +1 for libssh. ;-)